# Convert byte array to signed int64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, bignum, int64

I know that there is no int64 data type in js. But i need to convert a byte array into a signed int64 to get same result comparing to BitConverter.ToInt64() method in .NET class library. There is an implementations of big integers in javascript (BigInt.js) which accept hex as input and gets a bigInt as output but result is not same as BitConverter.ToInt64() in BCL.
Example:

```
BitConverter.ToInt64() for '0x40e00a35661f92a2' will result in -6732283969128439744
```

I need a solution for doing this in java script, performance is not issue.

edit:

feed data in normal order into BigInt.js:

```
javascript: new BigInt('0x40e00a35661f92a2')// shows 4674747637673464482
```

feed data in reverse order into BigInt.js:

```
javascript: new BigInt('0xa2921f66350ae040')// shows 11714460104581111872
```

which neither matches the BitConverter.ToInt64() result:

```
C SHARP: BitConverter.ToInt64(new byte[] { 0x40, 0xe0, 0x0a, 0x35, 0x66, 0x1f, 0x92, 0xa2 }, 0); // shows -6732283969128439744
```

Comment: What's BigInt's result? Did you check endianess? If your input number array is big-endian, reverse the byte-array if you need little-endian (or vica versa). That number should not be negative either as there is no sign bit set. The result should be 4674747637673464482 in decimal (little-endian). Seems as BitConverter is doing something funky (disclaimer: half asleep...).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg i've edited the question with result of BigInt.js in both little indian and big indian order

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg added more info

Comment: See if this can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implementation for converting hex string to Int64 (both signed and unsigned) here: [LINK](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/javascript-hex-string-to-int64-conversion-similar-to-int64-parse/)

That code returns right result:

```
javascript: new HexStringToInt64StringConverter(true).convert('a2921f66350ae040') // will return -6732283969128439744 same as BitConverter.ToInt64() in BCL
```

The functions from the link:

```
function HexStringToInt64StringConverter(signed) {
var hexCode = {
    '0':"0000",
    '1':"0001",
    '2':"0010",
    '3':"0011",
    '4':"0100",
    '5':"0101",
    '6':"0110",
    '7':"0111",
    '8':"1000",
    '9':"1001",
    'a':"1010",
    'b':"1011",
    'c':"1100",
    'd':"1101",
    'e':"1110",
    'f':"1111"
};
var preComputedLongMath = {
    "20":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    "21":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    "22":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
    "23":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
    "24":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6],
    "25":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2],
    "26":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4],
    "27":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 8],
    "28":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 6],
    "29":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2],
    "210":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4],
    "211":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 8],
    "212":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 9, 6],
    "213":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 2],
    "214":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 3, 8, 4],
    "215":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 7, 6, 8],
    "216":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 5, 3, 6],
    "217":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 7, 2],
    "218":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 2, 1, 4, 4],
    "219":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 4, 2, 8, 8],
    "220":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 8, 5, 7, 6],
    "221":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 9, 7, 1, 5, 2],
    "222":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 4, 3, 0, 4],
    "223":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 3, 8, 8, 6, 0, 8],
    "224":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 7, 7, 7, 2, 1, 6],
    "225":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2],
    "226":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 1, 0, 8, 8, 6, 4],
    "227":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 7, 2, 8],
    "228":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6],
    "229":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 6, 8, 7, 0, 9, 1, 2],
    "230":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 3, 7, 4, 1, 8, 2, 4],
    "231":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 4, 7, 4, 8, 3, 6, 4, 8],
    "232":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 9, 4, 9, 6, 7, 2, 9, 6],
    "233":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 5, 8, 9, 9, 3, 4, 5, 9, 2],
    "234":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 1, 7, 9, 8, 6, 9, 1, 8, 4],
    "235":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 5, 9, 7, 3, 8, 3, 6, 8],
    "236":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 7, 1, 9, 4, 7, 6, 7, 3, 6],
    "237":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 7, 4, 3, 8, 9, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    "238":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 4, 8, 7, 7, 9, 0, 6, 9, 4, 4],
    "239":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 9, 7, 5, 5, 8, 1, 3, 8, 8, 8],
    "240":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 9, 5, 1, 1, 6, 2, 7, 7, 7, 6],
    "241":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 9, 9, 0, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2],
    "242":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 9, 8, 0, 4, 6, 5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 4],
    "243":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 7, 9, 6, 0, 9, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 8],
    "244":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 5, 9, 2, 1, 8, 6, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 6],
    "245":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3, 7, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 3, 2],
    "246":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 6, 8, 7, 4, 4, 1, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4],
    "247":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 7, 3, 7, 4, 8, 8, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 8],
    "248":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 1, 4, 7, 4, 9, 7, 6, 7, 1, 0, 6, 5, 6],
    "249":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 2, 9, 4, 9, 9, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2],
    "250":[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 9, 9, 0, 6, 8, 4, 2, 6, 2, 4],
    "251":[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 5, 1, 7, 9, 9, 8, 1, 3, 6, 8, 5, 2, 4, 8],
    "252":[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 3, 5, 9, 9, 6, 2, 7, 3, 7, 0, 4, 9, 6],
    "253":[0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 1, 9, 9, 2, 5, 4, 7, 4, 0, 9, 9, 2],
    "254":[0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 1, 4, 3, 9, 8, 5, 0, 9, 4, 8, 1, 9, 8, 4],
    "255":[0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 2, 8, 7, 9, 7, 0, 1, 8, 9, 6, 3, 9, 6, 8],
    "256":[0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 5, 7, 5, 9, 4, 0, 3, 7, 9, 2, 7, 9, 3, 6],
    "257":[0, 0, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 5, 5, 8, 7, 2],
    "258":[0, 0, 2, 8, 8, 2, 3, 0, 3, 7, 6, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 1, 7, 4, 4],
    "259":[0, 0, 5, 7, 6, 4, 6, 0, 7, 5, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 8, 8],
    "260":[0, 1, 1, 5, 2, 9, 2, 1, 5, 0, 4, 6, 0, 6, 8, 4, 6, 9, 7, 6],
    "261":[0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 8, 4, 3, 0, 0, 9, 2, 1, 3, 6, 9, 3, 9, 5, 2],
    "262":[0, 4, 6, 1, 1, 6, 8, 6, 0, 1, 8, 4, 2, 7, 3, 8, 7, 9, 0, 4],
    "263":[0, 9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0, 8],
    "264":[1, 8, 4, 4, 6, 7, 4, 4, 0, 7, 3, 7, 0, 9, 5, 5, 1, 6, 1, 6],
    "265":[3, 6, 8, 9, 3, 4, 8, 8, 1, 4, 7, 4, 1, 9, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2]
};
if (typeof(signed) != 'boolean') signed = false;
function toBinary(hex) {
    hex = hex.toLowerCase();
    var binary = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i++) {
        binary += hexCode[hex[i]];
    }
    return binary;
}

function to1nsComplement(binary) {
    var compliment = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        compliment += (binary.charAt(i) == "1" ? "0" : "1");
    }
    return compliment;
}

function arrayAdd(a, b) {
    var carry = 0;
    var number = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    for (var i = 19; i >= 0; i--) {
        number[i] = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
        if (number[i].toString().length > 1) {
            carry = parseInt(number[i].toString().substring(0, number[i].toString().length - 1), 10);
            number[i] = parseInt(number[i].toString().substring(number[i].toString().length - 1), 10)
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    return number;
}

function removeZeroPad(number) {
    var lock = false;
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        if (lock) {
            output.push(number[i]);
        } else {
            if (number[i] != 0) {
                lock = true;
                output.push(number[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

function binaryToDec(binary) {
    var negative = false;
    if (signed && (binary.charAt(0) == 1)) {
        negative = true;
    }
    if (signed) {
        binary = binary.substring(1);
        if (negative) {
            binary = to1nsComplement(binary);
        }
    }
    var pos = 0;
    var number = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    for (var i = binary.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == 1) {
            number = arrayAdd(number, preComputedLongMath["2" + pos])
        }
        pos++;
    }
    if (negative) {
        number = removeZeroPad(arrayAdd(number, preComputedLongMath["20"]));
        number.splice(0, 0, "-");
    } else {
        number = removeZeroPad(number);
    }
    return number.join("");
}

this.convert = function (hex) {
    var binary = toBinary(hex);
    return binaryToDec(binary);
};
}
```

Comment: Link is dead. It's always a good idea to include the code directly in the answer (while providing a link to the source too).

Comment: That's good. Still, it could go away at any time. You should include the relevant code in your answer.